# Find the endpoints of 3D skeleton

Tags: matlab, image-processing

If one has a 3d skeleton of an image (e.g. via [`Skeleton3D()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43400-skeleton3d)), how can one find end points and branch-points? In 2D, one would do:

```
B = bwmorph(skel, 'branchpoints');
E = bwmorph(skel, 'endpoints');
```

But in 3D?

---

This is a "port" of the following question, with added information.

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/237405-find-the-endpoints-of-3d-skeleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the endpoints, the linked question in the post has an answer that is only partially correct. The correct way is:

```
E = (convn(double(skel3d),ones(3,3,3),'same')<3).*skel3d;
```

With similar logic, the following seems to give solid detection of branchpoints in my data:

```
B = (convn(double(skel3d),ones(3,3,3),'same')>3).*skel3d;
```

Comment: I would implement this with a simple comparison operator though: `(convn(..)<3) & skel3d`, and `(convn(...)>3) & skel3d`. Just because I think it's easier to read. Fewer than 3 points: either an end point or an isolated pixel. Exactly 3 points happens along branches. More than 3 points must be a branch point.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree! Fell free to edit it, otherwise I'll do it later. I left it like this due to the original answer being almost this, but I agree the ismember just obfuscation unecesarily

Comment: @CrisLuengo I <3 conv 2 :)